# Facebook Graph API + Python - empty data returned for insights

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Hi this is my code to get the page impressions from facebook. I don't get an error message, it simply returns empty data and then the paging 'previous' and 'next'. I do have page access authorisation with the right permissions.

```
pimp = graph.get_connections(id=page_id,
                                         connection_name='insights',
                                         metric='page_impressions_unique',
                                         date_preset='this_month',
                                         period='week',
                                         show_description_from_api_doc=True)
print(pimp)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the code. I can get the page info it I use:

```
page = graph.get_object(id=page_id, fields = 'about,name')
print(page)
```

Thanks for the help
Riana

Comment: Would suggest that you go and try the same request, using that same token, in Graph API Explorer first.

Comment: Hi thanks, it was a permission issue.. i thought "manage page" includes "view insights".. but i needed to add that.